# Best way to store usernames and passwords

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashmap, passwords, hashtable

I am in an intro to security class and we just learned that you are never supposed to actually store a user's password. Instead, you should hash it and store that along with their username.

This got me thinking, if I was building a web app and wanted to store the usernames and passwords - where/how would I store them?

I was thinking a hash map would be useful in this case since you have a key (username) and a value (the hashed password) but I would like to know if that's a good data structure to use or if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup a value using a key - here a password using a username, then you do need an associative container, aka map.  It doesn't really matter if the implementation of that map uses a hash table (i.e. it's a hash map, like C++'s `std::unordered_map` say), or a balanced binary tree (like `std::map` - they're both likely to be fast enough for most purposes.  If you had billions of users then the hash table would pull ahead performance wise, but if that was the case you could hire some experienced programmers and they'd have bigger concerns for a good while I'm sure.